# how to escape special characters of mariadb password in shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, mariadb

I what to write a shell script to loging in to mariadb. The shell script read one password containing special characters(blank, !@) in a ini file.

The OS is Ubuntu 18.04

the ini file as follows:

```
user=xxx-xxx-xxx
password=xxx /xxx /xx/ !\@
```

the shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
baseDir="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
iniPath="$baseDir/backup.ini"
echo "iniPath is $iniPath"

dbUser="$(grep 'user' $iniPath | cut -d '=' -f 2)"
echo "user is $dbUser"

dbPassword="$(grep 'password' $iniPath | cut -d '=' -f 2)"
echo "password is $dbPassword"

mysql -h localhost -u $dbUser -p'$dbPassword'
```

if I input the command as follows:
mysql -h localhost -u xxxxxx -p'xxx /xxx /xx/ !@'
in command line, it loging successfully.
But If I execute the shell script, it always results in accessing denied for user.

Have any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use: mysql -h localhost -u $dbUser -p'\`echo $dbPassword\`' ? (special character ` is on US like keyboards under esc key left upper corner, it looks like back apostroph)

Looks like the variable with password is not correctly "printed" into a mysql command before its run. Other way I would recommend trying is to use -p"$dbPassword"

Comment: It works fine with -p"$dbPassword". Thank you, Honza P.

Comment: Cool, I wrote it as an answer for anyone else with similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use: `` mysql -h localhost -u $dbUser -p'`echo $dbPassword`' ``? (special character **`** is on US like keyboards under esc key left upper corner, it looks like back apostroph) Looks like the variable with password is not correctly "printed" into a mysql command before its run.

Other way I would recommend trying is to use `-p"$dbPassword"`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the issue is that the shell will not interpolate variables into a string surrounded by single quotes. As Honza specified, the double-quotes will work.

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) for details.